# Error with viewmodel facotry and viewmodel module injecting thorugh Dagger, UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property viewModelFactory

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, androidinjector

I would like to show the one service result to the UI and the result has been modified dynamically. So, I have created MutableLiveData.

ResultViewModel

```
class ResultViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val lane: ResultManager
) : ViewModel() {

val result= MutableLiveData<String>()
    init {
      result.listener = object : ResultListener {
        override fun OnChange(value: String?) {
            result.postValue(value)
        }

      }
    }
}
```

and created the Generic viewmodel factory

```
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val creators: @JvmSuppressWildcards Map<Class<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>>
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        var creator: Provider<out ViewModel>? = creators[modelClass]
        if (creator == null) {
            for ((key, value) in creators) {
                if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(key)) {
                    creator = value
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        if (creator == null) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown model class: $modelClass")
        }
        try {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

and viewmodel for this factory has been created and added to the app component

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER)
@kotlin.annotation.Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
internal annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)


@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(ResultViewModel::class)
    abstract fun refultViewModel(viewModel: ResultViewModel ): ViewModel

}
```

and in my app component

```
@Singleton
@Component
    (modules = [AppModule::class,
    ViewModelModule::class])
interface AppComponent  {
       fun  Inject(result: ResultModule): ResultComponent
}

@Subcomponent(modules = [ResultModule::class, ResultViewModelModule::class])
interface ResultComponent {
    
    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)
}
```

and i have resultmodule as follows,

```
@Module
class ResultModule(private val resultId: Int) {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun refultManager(manager: ResultMonitor): ResultManager = manager.getManager(0)
}
```

In my main activity, I tried to get the app component and injected that activity

```
@Inject    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory
private val resultViewModel : ResultViewModel  by viewModels { viewModelFactory }
```

in onCreate, I tried to inject the activity.

```
var appComponent = Resultapp.Getcomponent()
appComponent.Inject(AfccLaneModule(0)).Inject(this)
```

but facing, Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property viewModelFactory has not been initialize

unable to find the route cause of the issue.